# Are there any data sources for tracking largest daily changes in stocks?

Tags: stock-analysis

I'm hoping to study stocks with the largest moves in a single day.  Is there either a website which provides historical data, or a webpage with sufficient parameters in the URL so that I can scrape past data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wall Street Journal provides a historical database of the largest advancing and declining stocks on the NYSE, the Nasdaq, and Arca (or a composite of all 3) going back 20+ years.  You have to do it a day at a time but hopefully it does the trick for you:

http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-losenyse-loser.html?mod=topnav_2_3002

Comment: Exactly what I need, especially with the clear structure of the dates.

Comment: I'm curious about data scraping of which I know nothing about.  Do you capture the data on each page  manually and scroll back historically one day at a time or do you write a program of sorts that collects the data?

Comment: Assuming that it's OK with a website (you have to check the terms), you write a program to go to the URL for you, then parse the HTML.  As an example, you can do this using Python (a programming language) and Beautiful Soup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: While it's well above my pay grade, thanks for the link.  It gave me an idea of what the scraping process involves.